# SQLAlchemy, filtering relationship data by field inside hybrid_method

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have one SQLAlchemy model that has data like this:

```
class Course(Base):

    name = Column(String(255))
    attempts = relationship('CompleteAttempt', back_populates='course')

    @hybrid_method
    def course_completeness_percent(self, user_id):
        return 0
```

And it's child model looks like this:

```
 class CompleteAttempt(Base):
     user_id = Column(Integer)
     status = Column(Enum(StatusEnum, name='status', create_type=False), 
                default=StatusEnum.pending,
                nullable=False)
```

These are very simplified examples.

What I need, is to filter only specific `CompleteAttemps` inside `course_completeness_percent` by value of `user_id` so I could calculate the percentage of completeness.

The main problem is that in SQLAlchemy documentation, there are no examples of data filtration on `hybrid_method`

Is it even possible?

Comment: I think it's doable. I am able to write the query if you redefine what you need, it's not totally clear to me. Also, you might want to have a look at this. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_method Maybe you need an `expression`?

Comment: @TomaszWojcik According to docs, there should be hybrid method and its expression. I know how to make an expression, but I don't know how to make method

Comment: Could you add your code for the expression to your question please? Ot might make the question a bit clearer.